# Why does command "tsc file.ts" give no output and not produce a js file?

Tags: makefile, typescript, linux-mint

I have just started work on a project with some typescript code, and I'm trying to compile the .ts files to .js files from within Linux Mint, but it's not working as I'd expect.

There is a Makefile, but it's not working. Running `make` returns an error:

```
tsc --noImplicitAny --noEmitOnError --out client/welcome.js client/welcome.ts
make: *** [client/welcome.js] Error 1
```

I have also tried creating an example typescript file greeter.ts (as per [this official tutorial](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial)) containing:

```
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}
var user = "Jane User";
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

and tried compiling the ts file to javascript with the command (as per the same tutorial) `tsc greeter.ts` however the command completes with no output, and no .js file has been created.

I haven't previously worked with typescript at all, and though I've used Makefile's before I don't know much about them either, so I'm hoping it's something really obvious!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> --noEmitOnError

This means that if there is an error detected *no js will be generated*. I highly recommend not using this option (Changes a major benefit of [why typescript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html))

## More

Check your `tsc` version. The code you provided works fine with `1.6`:

[image]

## Update

The `--version` command should work at the very least. See below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think that helps a little. Any idea for how to check the version? `tsc --version` does nothing, and there's no linux manual entry for tsc it seems.

Comment: `which tsc` should tell you the location of `tsc`

Comment: I found a line containing `ts.version = "1.6.2"` in line 29357 of the file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js  so perhaps that means I have version 1.6.2... would have been easier if it was at the top of the file!

Comment: @HighlyIrregular `tsc --version` should have definitely worked. I just tested it and it does work

Comment: Thanks... there must be something wrong with my installation. I'll focus on that.

Comment: Make sure when you installed typescript that you installed it with `-g` which means it would be installed globally. If not you will have to reference the `tsc` command from within the node_modules folder.

Comment: discussion continuing here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835203/whats-wrong-with-my-typescript-compiler-tsc-version-returns-nothing

Comment: Also `--listEmittedFiles` might helpful

Answer (score 59):

I encountered this problem because I had the following line in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"noEmit": true
```

It worked after removing it.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible that tsc may not output js files due to param:

```
"emitDeclarationOnly": true
```

in your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have this entry in `tsconfig.json` which only has `"./src/types/global.d.ts"`:

```
{
  ...
  "files": [
    "./src/types/global.d.ts"
  ]
  ...
}
```

**Solution # 1**

You can delete the whole `files` entry.

**Solution # 2**

Add `include` in your `tsconfig.json` which has the folder which you want `tsc` to build:

```
{
  "files": [ ... ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**.*.ts"
  ],
}
```

I have my `server.ts` in the `src` directory. I run the following command `npm run build` (which is just `tsc` in `package.json`), and the build file is now successfully created.