# What's wrong with my typescript compiler? `tsc --version` returns nothing

Tags: node.js, typescript, linux-mint

In Linux Mint, I've installed node and used it to install typescript. With a working typescript installation, `tsc --version` should return the version number. In my case, nothing is returned at all.

When I run `which tsc` the result is `/usr/local/bin/tsc`.

When I run `cat /usr/local/bin/tsc` the result is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../lib/tsc.js')
```

When I run `find /usr/local -name 'tsc*'` the result is:

```
/usr/local/bin/tsc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js
```

**Does that look correct? If so, then any ideas on what else to look at would be appreciated?**

Note I also tried running `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --version` and got the same result ie nothing.

Comment: Weird. Does `node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js --version` work?

Comment: @DavidSherret Nice point. Might be a bad node install

Comment: @DavidSherret no, it doesn't. Any idea how to reinstall node? :-)

Comment: @DavidSherret I discovered that even `node --version` returns nothing (but shouldn't) however `nodejs --version` works, and so does the command you suggested when I call nodejs instead of node. I wonder why that would be. Reinstalling node didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered that running `node --version` returns nothing (but shouldn't) however `nodejs --version` works (the result being `v0.10.25`). Reinstalling node didn't fix this. I don't know why this would be the case, as I think I followed the recommended installation procedure.

However, editing file /usr/local/bin/tsc and changing the line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```

seemed to work. Now `tsc --version` returns `message TS6029: Version 1.6.2` and I'm getting .js files generated when I run `make`.

Comment: Fix works for Azure Ubuntu 14.04.4 instance. You should set it as the answer.

Answer (score 13):

In my case on Ubuntu 16.04 the problem was because of I performed `sudo apt-get install node-typescript`, which delivered me broken tsc. After removing it via `apt-get remove` and then installing as recommended with `npm install -g typescript`, it worked fine.

Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the following error in Ubuntu 16.04.6 :

```
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
   throw err;
   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript/tsc.js'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/bin/tsc:2:1)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Running : `npm install -g typescript` didn't resolved the issue.
So, I had to install the latest version of node i.e `nvm install <nvm version>`

Then with `npm install` , it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, removing `node_modules` and running `npm i` or `yarn` can solve the issue.